# wp_schedule_single_event() for existing action

Tags: php, wordpress, function, action, buddypress

Trying do make this work, unfortunately without success.
The user should receive a message 5 minutes after registration.
Any solutions?

```
function bp_messages_first_message( $user_id = false, $key = false, $user = false ){
    if ( ! function_exists( 'BP_Better_Messages' ) ) return false;

    $args = array(
        'sender_id'  => 88,
        'thread_id'  => false,
        'recipients' => $user_id,
        'content'    => "test",
        'date_sent'  => bp_core_current_time()
    );
    
    $result = BP_Better_Messages()->functions->new_message( $args );
}

function do_this_in_5_minutes() {
    add_action('bp_core_activated_user', 'bp_messages_first_message', 10, 3);
}
add_action( 'message_5','do_this_in_5_minutes' );
wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 300, 'message_5' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Then it would make sense to schedule the event when the registration happens.

Not tested:

```
<?php

function do_this_in_5_minutes($user_id) {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'BP_Better_Messages' ) ) return false;

    $args = array(
        'sender_id'  => 88,
        'thread_id'  => false,
        'recipients' => $user_id,
        'content'    => "test",
        'date_sent'  => bp_core_current_time()
    );
    
    $result = BP_Better_Messages()->functions->new_message( $args );
}


add_action('bp_core_activated_user', function($user_id = false, $key = false, $user = false) {
    add_action( 'message_5','do_this_in_5_minutes');
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 300, 'message_5', [$user_id]);

}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: no, does not work